# Understanding a change of measure in an integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am following a set of notes that says the following:

Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on some measure space $X$, and $f: X \rightarrow X$ is a continuous function. Then $f(\mu)$ is a measure defined as follows
$$f(\mu)(E) = \mu(f^{-1}(E)), \quad \forall E \subset X.$$
Moreover, for any continuous and bounded $\phi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then
$$\int \phi(g)\,df(\mu)(g) = \int\phi(f(g))\,d\mu(g).$$
I am having trouble understanding how these two integrals are equivalent on a formal level, and also what this result is saying on an intuitive level.

Comment: Algthough it is not continuous, look at what this gives for [$\phi={\bf1}_E$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Comment: Then simple functions and then some limits.